# iPad 4th not recognised when connected via USB-C Apple Digital AV Multiport Adapter on Catalia

Tags: ipad, catalina, usb

If I connect my iPad 4th generation to the MacbookPro 2020 with Catalina 10.15.6 directly via USB-C cable, everything works well: the iPad shows in the finder.

If I do the same, but I plug the usb-c cable in the Apple Multiport adapter (last generation), nothing happens.

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try contacting Apple support?

Answer (score 2):

The Apple Multi-port adapter only provides **power** via the usb-c out connection.

You could use the older USB-A port to get USB 3 speeds if needed THOUGH early iPads top out at USB 2 on the Lightning adapter.

Full details of the connector are on the Apple site [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207806)